# Is it possible to only show the layered navigation on specific category pages?

Tags: layered-navigation

I would like to the layered navigation to only show up on specific category pages. Is this possible without a custom extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Is Anchor" setting in the "Display Settings" tab of the category edit in the admin should do it. If it is set to 'yes' the layered navigation should the frontend for that category. Make sure to you are in the correct store this is a multi-store instance of Magento.